# could not find or load class org.testng.TestNg

Tags: ant, testng

I am trying to understand how to use Ant script and testNG. I am new to Ant

I am following this tutorial Link http://seleniumeasy.com/ant-tutorials/how-to-run-testng-tests-using-build-xml-file

The build seems to be successful however i get the following error in cmd :

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.testing.Test`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have local code that declares a package of "org.testing"? Much better idea to ensure your classes belong to a namespace peculiar to you.

The Selenium imports are:

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Comment: My classes do belong to a namespace as you mentioned above. I have followed this tutorial exactly.http://seleniumeasy.com/ant-tutorials/how-to-run-testng-tests-using-build-xml-file

Comment: Can't help you further. You need to provide more information, for example which line of the ANT file is failing and the stacktrace.